# Problem in using ArcMap

Tags: arcmap

The feature disappears in data view when I use full extent button in ArcMap 10.4.1

How can I deal with this problem ?

Comment: Does the map has one layer or more?

Comment: the map has many layers. Sometimes it works normally, but sometimes it does not

Answer (score 1):

Open ArcCatalog and right click to the feature class. In feature extend you will find 4 corners coordinates, you can modify manually or you just click **Recalculate** and ArcCatalog will recalculate the extent depending the data.

[image]

Comment: This will not address the issue of an improperly defined spatial reference.

Comment: If he/she has just extends issue, this is the solution. Otherwise other checks may be required.

Comment: next time, I will try this for my project. Now, it's going well